# How to push second array into first array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two while loops to get two different values as array those are called heading and menu.In that i want a result like menu array values are inside heading array.

This is my code:

```
        $heading = array();
        $menu = array();
        $stmt_heading = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT main_heading_name,sub_heading_name FROM `selected_food_main_sub_heading` WHERE branch_id = ? AND brand_id = ? AND business_id = ? ");
        $stmt_heading->bind_param("iii",  $branch_id, $brand_id,$business_id);
        $stmt_heading->execute();
        $result = $stmt_heading->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            array_push($heading, $row);
            $stmt_menu = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `menu_deatils` WHERE main_heading_name = ? AND sub_heading_name = ? ");
            $stmt_menu->bind_param("ss",  $row['main_heading_name'], $row['sub_heading_name']);
            $stmt_menu->execute();
            $result_menu = $stmt_menu->get_result();
            while ($row_menu = $result_menu->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                array_push($menu, $row_menu);
            }
            $data['menu_list'] = $menu;
            array_push($heading, $data);
            $stmt_menu->close();

        }
        return $heading;
```

Heading array values:

```
[
      {
        "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
        "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
      },
      {
        "main_heading_name": "Bites",
        "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
      }
]
```

Menu array values:

```
{
    "menu_list": [{
            "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
            "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
        },
        {
            "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
            "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want a result like:

```
  [
      {
            "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
            "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice",
            "menu_list": [{
                    "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
                    "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
                },
                {
                    "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
                    "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "main_heading_name": "Bites",
            "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice",
            "menu_list": [{
                    "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
                    "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
                },
                {
                    "main_heading_name": "Quick Bites",
                    "sub_heading_name": "Biryani & Rice"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

How can do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would `array_merge($array1, $array2);` help you?

Comment: array_merge gives merged array values.I want Second array inside first array and second array as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
$FullArray1 = $menu + $heading;
$FullArray2 = array_merge($menu, $heading);
```

Both of these will give the intended result.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Edit: In response to your comment

```
array_push($menu, $heading);
```

Comment: I don't want  merged array i need second array inside first array